# Why my Google Assistant chatbot built on Dialogflow only works fine on the test console?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am building a chatbot with Dialogflow and plan to integrate it on Google Assistant. The purpose of the bot would be to present to the user the different foods available in a restaurant.

## My Intents

**1.** I have a first Intent (let's call it intent A) that is triggered when the user asks for the available foods.
The bot then replies and asks the user to choose in a list between "starters", "main courses" and "desserts".

**2.** A follow-up intent to intent A (let's call it intent B) should be triggered when the users clicks on "main courses", displaying the available main courses.

## What happens

Now, when I am testing this sequence on the testing console (with Actions on Google selected), things seem to work fine. However, when i go on my phone and repeat the same sequence on the Google Assistant app, intent B doesn't seem to be triggered when I click on "main courses" since the bot replies with "i don't think i understood" which means the Default Fallback Intent was triggered.

*Also, I got to mention that sometimes it worked correctly randomly eventhough i was repeating the same sequence whitout modifying anything.*

*"main courses" is part of the training phrases of intent B and the output contexts of intent A match the input contexts of intent B.*

I don't understand why things work fine on the test console but don't on my phone.

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrJlF.jpg)

Do you guys know where the problem could be from?

Comment: It is difficult to tell just from your description. Can you update your question to include screen shots of the two Intents, of it working in the simulator, and what it looks like on an actual device?

Comment: You should see a link now